# How can I get the currently playing media metadata in rust

Tags: rust, audio, metadata, tauri

I have tried several crates but don't seem to get it.
For more information, i'm trying to use it in Tauri, I'm not very good at Rust as I'm a Javascript dev

```
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]
use playerctl::{PlayerCtl, TrackMetadata};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tauri::{AppHandle, Manager};

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Metadata {
    artist: String,
    title: String,
    album: String,
    // Add other fields as needed
}

#[tauri::command]
 fn get_current_media_metadata(app_handle: AppHandle) -> Result<Metadata, String> {
    let track_metadata = PlayerCtl::metadata();

    let metadata = Metadata {
        artist: track_metadata.artist,
        title: track_metadata.title,
        album: track_metadata.album,
        // Add other fields as needed
    };

    Ok(metadata)
}

fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![get_current_media_metadata])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("failed to run app");
}
```

All I get as error is:

```
thread 'main' panicked at /home/n3rd/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/playerctl-0.1.0/src/lib.rs:40:29:
Failed to execute command 'playerctl metadata title'
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Looks like you did not install the [playerctl commandline utility](https://github.com/altdesktop/playerctl). The crate you use is only a wrapper for the utility and you have to install the commandline utility and add it to your `PATH`.

Comment: Ohh.. so does that mean it’ll have to be installed manually on the system or is there a way to use it without mandating it being preinstalled?

Comment: Well the command `playerctl` has to be available from where you run your command, that most likely means you need to manually install it, yes.

Comment: Thanks man, this is very helpful, got it to work, so will probably add as a dependency or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cafce25 pointed out you'd need to install `playerctl` on the target system.

the proper way to do it would be to wrap C/C++ library code with the Rust wrapper and call it inside your code. Someone already did an attempt on it:
[playerctl-sys](https://crates.io/crates/playerctl-sys) so this might work better for you. And it should compile the code for your platform, and your user won't need to install it separately.

Checkout their [tests source code](https://github.com/ap-1/playerctl-sys/blob/main/src/lib.rs) to get a better understanding how to get metadata for your purpose.